# PHPMailer, DKIM, and SPF set - Emails still arriving in Junk (PHP)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, spf

I am trying to send an activation email from my website to the user. No matter what I do, the email is going straight to the junk folder.

I have logged into my cPanel, gone to E-Mail Authentication and enabled Domain Keys and SPF, but to no avail.

It's also worth mentioning that I'm using PHPMailer class with the default mail() type. I tried using sendmail, but it was unable to execute (shared host), and I tried SMTP, but I don't have the details for that (as far as I know).

Is there anything else I need to do?

Here is the code that is sending the email for your reference.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['registered'])) {
    require_once '/home/wwwmcser/public_html/inc/vendor/class.phpmailer.php';

    //mail
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SetFrom('team@mcserverranks.com','MCSR Team');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('noreply@mcserverranks.com','No Reply');
    $mail->AddAddress($_SESSION['userEmail'],$_SESSION['userName']);
    $mail->Subject = 'Verify your account || MCServerRanks';
    $mail->Body = "removed";
    $mail->AltBody = "removed";
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        $_SESSION['mailErr'] = 'There was an error sending your mail. This has been reported. Please contact support for assistance.';
        error_log('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }
    unset($_SESSION['userEmail']);unset($_SESSION['userName']);unset($_SESSION['activateHash']);
    //show page
    //rest of page is shown below, but I've removed that
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happening due to the irregularities with in the Host address and From Address which You are sending the mail. If both these address doesn't belongs to same server then the mailing app will detect that mail as spam or junk.

```
$mail->Host='mail.developerbaijan.com';
$mail->Username='developerbaijan@gmail.com';
```

This will obviously resulting in junk mail due to the irregularity in host and user. If the from address is so may also end up the mail in the same.

You Should try like this

```
$mail->Host='mail.google.com';
$mail->Port=587;
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
$mail->Username='username@google.com';
$mail->Password='*********';
$mail->setFrom('username@google.com','name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the SPF records are added to the DNS TXT record. SPF record is relative to the domain you use for expedition
So if you want to send an E-mail as user@foo.bar from IP address **192.168.3.4** you need to create (if you are not the admin of foo.bar) a DNS TXT record/s for foo.bar as such

```
v=spf1 +ip4:192.168.3.4 -all
```

This tells the remote server that the foo.bar domain sends legitimate email from 192.168.3.4 and that all other sources are only pretending to be foo.bar.

Note that the IP can be either ip4 or ip6.

Also you can add Subnets, FQDN names, MX records, or include SPF records from other domains, use a single SPF record per domain with as many items as needed

See [SPF Documentation](https://www.spf-record.com/syntax)

Comment: openspf.org link now dead

Comment: @suspectus you can always google SPF record structure

Answer (score 0):

Set your address as being their address in the automated e-mail so they receive an e-mail from what appears to be their own email with a "authentication required .. success"  etc as title - this will prevent junk problem but may confuse some clients unless specified on site

Comment: That seems kind of dirty...no?

Comment: It works - depends upon your website if its a professional one - then this is not the way to go - it's just a simple solution for the junk problem - even some of my wanted e-mails arrive in the junk so albeit this is dodgy it works!

Comment: The website is professional unfortunately. Now however, I've noticed that it *seems* to just be microsoft services (hotmail, outlook, msn) that are noticing it as spam. gMail handles it as is expected, so I'm a bit weirded out.

Comment: this workaround do not work nowadays. anyway this is not a solution for the problem. You should check your SPF (TXT entry) in your DNS.